# Is it possible to forecast mean annual temperature, with mean annual temperature data from previous years using linear regression in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a mean annual temperature time series dataset (nhtemp in datasets package in R) from 1912 to 1972. I have to determine if I can forecast temperature using the two previous years using linear regression. I'm a little lost and don't know how to tackle the problem. Any help here?

I tried using multiple linear regression model with lag(nhtemp,-1) and lag(nhtemp,-2) but I don't know if this is working.

Comment: look here https://search.r-project.org/R/refmans/stats/html/simulate.html